# Using android two way databinding with checkbox

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm trying to use android two-way `databinding` with `checkBox` in a fragment.
I have multiple fragments in `viewPager` with custom `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and one `viewModel` in first `fragment`.
I have a checkbox with the code below:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_accept_rules"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@={viewmodel.isAccept}"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="text..." />
```

In viewModel:

```
private final ObservableBoolean isAccept = new ObservableBoolean(false);
```

When I go to last `fragment` and return to first one the `checkBox` is not checked anymore, the color of the checkbox is true but the check icon is not there!
Had anyone this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it was a bug in android support library because after update problem was disappear

Comment: @Sepher, which version to update?

Comment: @mochadwi latest version 27.1.1

Comment: @Sepher did you use AS 3.1.2 version as well? I've update the support library to 27.1.1, but still doesn't fix the checkbox problem T_T

Comment: @mochadwi yes , i use android studio 3.1.2 with gradle:3.0.0 if it helps!

Comment: thank you very much yaaa, will check by tommorrow for the updates~

Comment: @Sepehr Do you find any solution for this issue. Please guide me.

Comment: I have the same issue, with the latest libraries.

Answer (score 0):

View pager's fragment has an unique lifecycle than usual fragment.If you have three fragments A->B->C and you swipe B from C then fragment A will be destroyed.You can check it by override a method `onDestroy` in Fragment A.When you again swipe to A it will recreate again,and all the value will initialize again.That is the reason your checkbox's value is unchecked.Try to save checkbox's value in sharedPreference,so whenever it will recreate it will take the value's from sharedPreference and remeber to clear the sharedPrefence value when your viewpager will be destroyed or it'scontainer activity destroyed.